# Can I override or set the confirm function buttons' text

Tags: javascript, html

I use method confirmation when a user delete something(like a category) as

```
   <input id="id1"  class="button" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")" type="submit>            <input/>
```

It correctly works. But my website support multilanguage. Here is question; How can i set confirmation buttons text for each language? Confirmation screen language is default browser's language but I want to set these buttons text for each language. For example:
in english "Confirm " and "Cancel" buttons but in turkish "Onayla" and "Vazgeç" buttons.

Comment: Prompt box language is decided by the operating system/application - it's not something that can be changed by a web page.

Comment: are you in the desktop environment or working in mobile space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create custom dialog/confirm boxes in that case, the built-in confirm is based on the browser language and can not be changed.